# Category add excerpt WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type, named Products.

In here, I have different categories. Named external and internal products.

Here is my issue.
I have this screen:

[image: current screen]

I need an option for an excerpt, so the user can't just add a load of content.

Is this possible?!

Comment: Apologies! Changed it :)

Comment: If you google *wordpress add custom field to taxonomy* you'll find plenty of examples